# Css being overridden?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I'm using material ui for a react app.  I'm also using material table.  My nav bar just uses the default styling that material ui provides.  This has been working fine.  However when I add material table to the page, the nav bar goes from blue to white!  I'm not sure how to resolve this.  The code is below:

```
class ProfilePage extends React.Component {

  render() {

    const rows = [
      { title: "Time", field: "time" },
      { title: "Type", field: "type" },
      { title: "Feature", field: "feature" },
      { title: "Weight", field: "weight" }
    ];

    const {Profile, error, match } = this.props;
    const features = Profile;
    const userId = `ID: ${match.params.userId}`;

    if (error || Object.entries(tasteProfile).length === 0) {
      toastr.error(error);
      featureTable = <h2>Couldn't find profiles for that id</h2>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <NavBar />
        <Typography id="userId" variant="h6" color="inherit">
          {userId}
        </Typography>
        <Paper> 
        <div>
      <MaterialTable
        title="Profiles"
        columns={rows}
        data={features["features"]}
        >
        </MaterialTable>
    </div>
        </Paper>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Grateful for any help!

Comment: I have the same issue I believe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57204404/adding-component-with-material-table-changes-material-ui-appbar-style

I came across https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56794892/material-table-styling-is-overiding-all-custom-and-material-ui-styling-and-icon and will try to sort out the two different `material-ui/core` versions

Answer (score 1):

Try using the same versions of material-ui/core and material-ui/icons that material-table uses as seen in the `package-lock.json` file. I was able to fix my AppBar CSS style issue by downgrading these to the same version.

```
npm uninstall @material-ui/core
npm uninstall @material-ui/icons

npm install @material-ui/core@4.0.1
npm install @material-ui/icons@4.0.1
```

Comment: Thanks, Saved me from a lot of trouble

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including the `Material table` stylesheet before the `Material UI kit` one?